# como recuperar datos desde sql server y mostrar en un label

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

estoy creando una aplicación de control de gastos en C# y sql server, quisiera saber si existe una forma de recuperar los datos desde la base de datos y mostrar en un label, es decir, tengo una sección en dónde quiero mostrar las categorías con mayor gastos en el mes (como se muestra en la siguiente imagen)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya tengo un select en la base de datos en dónde logro agrupar la información, el problema es cómo lo recupero desde visual studio, los datos que quiero mostrar son la imagen de la categoría, el nombre y el monto total, esto es por mes, además es aleatorio, es decir, que siempre se mostrarán los primeros siete categorías con mayor importe. Si alguien puede echarme una manita, gracias!

Comment: Con un query a la base de datos.. cual es el problema que tuviste?

Comment: el problema es que no se como implementarlo en visual studio :(

Comment: Revisa un tutorial ejemplo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7hgcQC9FNJA&ab_channel=pildorasinformaticas despues agrega tus dudas en el foro, adjuntando el codigo que hayas intentado

Answer (score -2):

Crea un procedimiento en el que te conectes a la base de datos, haz el `select` y guarda los datos en un `sqldatareader` y después solo tienes que decir, ejemplo:

```
Label1.text = Tabla.Rows[0]["Categoría"].ToString();
```

Y ya, así a todos los que quieres.

Comment: Se valora tus ganas de responder, pero en StackOverflow se busca responder de manera puntual a preguntas bien formuladas, te invito a leer [answer].